# Model/library lazy load in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to do like this in CodeIgniter:

```
$this->load->model('Test_model');
$this->Test_model->....
```

I want just:

```
$this->Test_model->...
```

I don't wanna autoload all models, I want to load model on demand.
How can I add "lazy load" logic to `CI_Controller`? `__get()`? What logic should I add?

Thanks in advance!

PS Please don't confuse my question with [CodeIgniter lazy-loading libraries/models/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011271/codeigniter-lazy-loading-libraries-models-etc) - we have different targets.

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

Update your `CI_Controller::__construct()` (path `system/core/Controller/`) like

```
foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
{
        $this->$var = '';
        $this->$var =& load_class($class);
}

$this->load = '';
$this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');
```

Then add a new method to `CI_Controller` class

```
public function &__get($name)
{
//code here from @Twisted1919's answer
}
```

Comment: This helped me; but I came up with a better solution that doesn't require modifying core and loads models (even in sub folders) and libraries http://stackoverflow.com/a/35282869/627473

Answer (score 3):

**The below seems to not work in ci(matter a fact, magic methods won't work), i'll leave it here as a refrence though for others.**

Well, in your specific case, this should do it (in your MY_Controller):

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if (!empty($this->$name) && $this->$name instanceof CI_Model) {
        return $this->$name;
    }
    if (is_file(APPPATH.'models/'.$name.'.php')) {
        $this->load->model($name);
        return $this->$name;
    }
}
```

L.E, second try:

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if (isset($this->$name) && $this->$name instanceof CI_Model) {
        return $this->$name;
    }
    if (is_file($modelFile = APPPATH.'models/'.$name.'.php')) {
        require_once ($modelFile);
        return $this->$name = new $name();
    }
}
```

But also, you need to watch for helpers, libraries, etc.

Comment: Message: Indirect modification of overloaded property Mainpage::$benchmark has no effect ---

Fatal error: Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object in \system\core\Controller.php on line 50

Comment: I've added this function to "class Mainpage extends CI_Controller " and got an error. I will make "MY_Controller" later. Mainpage is a controller.

Comment: You need to also detect if a model is already loaded and return that if it is.

Comment: I have a strange problem with "Benchmark" class...that stops me going further.

Comment: following @Orangepill advice, i updated the code. (haven't work with CI for a while now)

Comment: Same error - "Message: Indirect modification of overloaded property Mainpage::$benchmark has no effect"

Comment: might need to test like `if (!$this->load->is_loaded($name))` if think doing isset($this->$name) is going to trigger another call to __get...

Comment: I think is_loaded doesn't check for models.

Comment: even if you try the second approach?

Comment: I don't know what "Message: Indirect modification of overloaded property Mainpage::$benchmark has no effect" is.

Comment: It appears in these lines in CI_Controller:

foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
  {
   $this->$var =& load_class($class);
  }

Comment: @Twisted1919, yep - it will not help me - cuz of an error I got ('benchmark').

Comment: well, that made me curious. Let me install ci and see how it goes for me :)

Comment: @Twisted1919 - That would be awesome - you can easily modify "CI_Controller::__get" or "YourCustomController::__get" to let this task be finished.

Comment: @Vitalmax -Nope, unfortunatelly there is no way to do it because of the way CI loads libraries. You have to modify the core code to accomplish that.

Comment: @Twisted1919 - please post how should I modify the core to let me accept your answer.

Comment: Well, you have to play with `__set` and `__get` in `CI_Controller`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get and in your `__get` method have a check in the models directory like i did in my above example.

Comment: @Twisted1919 - thanks; I've played with "__get" and updated my question with "current solution". Thank you!!!

Comment: @Vitalmax - glad you sorted it out. this was a good exercise for you. Anyway, you need to have your eyes open on this and see if you get any unexpected behavior during development, also, keep a note when upgrading CI, you'll want that code from the controller ported too :)

Comment: This doesn't work in CI 3.0.4. I would like to know if there was a good way to do this. I will dig into and it and if I find a good way will post. I am getting Message: Indirect modification of overloaded property Home::$benchmark has no effect