# lazy load models and libraries in CI 3 __get magic method of controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am attempting to write a lazy loader for models + libraries in CI 3.0.4

I am trying to get the following as described in:

[Model/library lazy load in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579449/model-library-lazy-load-in-codeigniter)

This code seems to be for CI version 2 and when I tried to apply it to CI version 3.0.4 I get the following errors.

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Indirect modification of overloaded property Items::$benchmark has no effect

Filename: core/Controller.php

Line Number: 75


Fatal error: Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phppos/PHP-Point-Of-Sale/system/core/Controller.php on line 75
```

Here is what I did:

1. Create file application/core/MY_Controller.php
2. Create the following code:

   ```
       //Lazy load based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579449/model-library-lazy-load-in-codeigniter
       function __get($name)
       {
          if (isset($this->$name) && $this->$name instanceof CI_Model) 
           {
                 return $this->$name;
           }
       }
     }
   ```

Once I can get this to work without errors; I will add my custom logic to load the right model or library.

I want to do this WITHOUT modifying core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on example I have come up with the following that does NOT require core modifications and works in CI 3.0.4. It first tries to load a model and if the model does NOT exist it attempts to load a library.

1. Create file application/core/MY_Controller.php
2. Put these contents in it.

   ```
   <?php
   class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
   {

       //Lazy loading based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579449/model-library-lazy-load-in-codeigniter
       public function __construct()
       {
           foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
           {
                $this->$var = '';
           }

           $this->load = '';
           parent::__construct();
       }


       // Lazy load models + libraries....If we can't load a model that we have; then we will try to load library $name
       public function __get($name)
       {
           //Cache models so we only scan model dir once

           static $models = FALSE;
           $this->load->helper('file');

           if (!$models)
           {
               $model_files = get_filenames(APPPATH.'models', TRUE);
               foreach($model_files as $model_file)
               {
                   $model_relative_name = str_replace('.php','',substr($model_file,strlen(APPPATH.'models'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)));
                   $model_folder = strpos($model_relative_name, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) !== FALSE ? substr($model_relative_name,0,strrpos($model_relative_name,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) : '';
                   $model_name = str_replace($model_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '',$model_relative_name);

                   $models[$model_name] = $model_folder.'/'.$model_name;
               }
           }

           if (isset($models[$name]))
           {
               $this->load->model($models[$name]);
               return $this->$name;
           }
           else //Try a library if we cannot load a model
           {
               $this->load->library($name);
               return $this->$name;
           }

           return NULL;
       }
   }
   ```